# Google Maps API v3 custom cursor's hotspot in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, cursor

I've heard of Google Chrome having trouble with custom cursor hotspots before, but I am not sure of how to work around those problems in my situation because the custom cursor is being used by Google Maps API v3. I have a cursor I designed and saved as a .cur file. The hotspot is set to the bottom left hand corner. I set this by setting the ruler start spot in Photoshop CS5. The cursor works perfectly in Firefox and Safari, but in Google Chrome the hotspot remains in the top left corner. I'm also getting this warning in Chrome's console: "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream." What do I do?

Here is the jsFiddle. You'll find that it works in Safari or Firefox, but not Chrome (on Mac).

http://jsfiddle.net/ruXhf/1/

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `.htaccess` file

```
AddType image/vnd.microsoft.icon .cur .ico
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm no longer getting the warning, but the hotspot is still in the upper left corner.

Comment: put it up on jsfiddle or something so we can inspect it. without looking directly @ the code, i can't help you anymore.

Comment: meh. i overlooked that you were on os x. i can't even replicate it. check it out though: on win7 it works in chrome 22.0.1229.2, ff 14.0.1, safari 5.1.7.
does not work - win7 opera 12.01
does work - linux mint - chrome 20.0.1132  looks like it's a bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109918   however, this says to preload the cursor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959843/cursor-disappears-in-google-maps-application    if that doesn't work, i'd simply feature detect if you're in chrome os x and add it via JavaScript. good luck.